# Ubuntu 20.04, nouveau driver fails to load correct firmware file

Tags: ubuntu, firmware, nouveau

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Precision M6400. No hardware acceleration (glmark2 displays smooth graphics but CPU goes to 100%) and nouveau errors in dmesg...

```
dmesg | grep nouveau

[ 2497.539054] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nv84_xuc00f failed with error -2
[ 2497.539066] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: unable to load firmware nouveau/nv84_xuc00f
[ 2497.539070] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: vp: init failed, -2
```

Nvidia video card...

```
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev,nouveau unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz, 1600x1200~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NV92 v: 3.3 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Checking https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/CodeNames.html I find that the correct firmware for my card is listed under NV50 family (Tesla) as NV92(G92).  In my /lib/firmware/nouveau I find...

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1627 Dec 12  2009 nv92.ctxprog
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 19689 Dec 12  2009 nv92.ctxvals
```

Are these the firmware files it's looking for ?  If so how do I get it to use these nv92 files instead of nv84_xuc00f?  I have searched for information about 'vp: init failed, -2' and how nouveau loads its firmware files but detail seems a bit thin.

Any pointers would be much appreciated ?

GB

Comment: Please report here instead https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/nouveau/-/issues/